# css dock table background image to the right without stretching horizontally

Tags: html, css

I have a table, and a long image, i want to put the image as a background for the table, only that i want it to be docked on the right, with a width lets say 20% of the right column (( table has 2 columns )).

The table has a height that is equal to the sum of the heights of all the rows, so if the windows browser gets smaller, it will create a scroll on the page, and I want my image to behave the same !!

How can i achieve that in css without the use of js ?? whether it's a (( css background image )) or `<img>` tag that will be fixed by some css rule.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find your question a little confusing, but here's a stab at what I think you're asking for.

http://jsfiddle.net/nate/7PcFJ/

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/100/800);
    background-position: 100% 0;
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    /* Set the background image to be 20% of the width of the table, and 800px */
    background-size: 20% 800px;
    width: 100%;
}

td {
    border: 5px solid orange;
}
```

In this example, we set a tall background image on the table. We use `background-position` to dock it to the right side. We use `background-repeat` to tell it only to repeat vertically. Then we use `background-size` to set its width to 20% of the table.

In your question, you asked for it to be set to 20% *of the right column*. That's trickier - you'd have to set the background image on the `td`s themselves, then, *or* have a fixed-width table. If you know the width of your table, it's easy to set the width of your background image relative to it.

Does this help?

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, it was of much help actually, it's almost what i want, i'll use this to implement the feature i want, thank you so much =)